# Gradle's javadoc goal does not copy files from doc-files

Tags: gradle, javadoc

I found that gradle's `javadoc` task does not copy files from `doc-files` subdirectories of package directories.

Is this possible to fix it?

Comment: working on a solution for this as i have a similar need. will be included with the next gradle fury release https://github.com/chrisdoyle/gradle-fury/issues/108

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably yes. You can add an action to `javadoc` with `<<`:

```
javadoc << {
   //copy all the files here
}
```

or create a task that will finalize `javadoc` and copy the files:

```
task copySub(type: Copy) {
   //configuration goes here
}

javadoc.finalizedBy(copySub)
```

Comment: Thanks. But didn't understand, how to refer numerous `doc-files` folders from my project tree?

Comment: @Dimes, you just need to find these files using groovy methods, or if such files were created by other tasks, using outputs of these tasks.

Comment: This is what I was afraid of :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bit late, but I just ran into the same issues and implemented a fix as part of [Gradle-Fury](https://github.com/gradle-fury/gradle-fury)

Basically, I injected a new task inbetween Javadoc and the Jar task for Javadoc (covering both android and regular java projects) that copies from the src/main/java or from src/variant/java with a pattern match for doc-files.

```
copy {
    from f.absolutePath
    into "$project.buildDir/docs/javadoc/"
    include "**/doc-files/*"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<< is now deprecated and should use doLast.

```
javadoc {
     // ...
     // ...
     doLast{
           copy{
                    from "<src-package>/doc-files"
                    into "$project.buildDir/docs/javadoc/<src-package>/doc-files"
                    include "*.png"
                }
           copy{
               }
            }
     }
```

Can use above to copy from multiple folders

Answer (score 0):

I tried first this approach:

```
javadoc {
  …
  doLast {
    copy {
      from "$projectDir/src/main/java"
      into "$project.docsDir/javadoc"
      include "**/doc-files/*"
    }
  }
}
```

but I found that it does not work for Java modules (Jigsaw), because for them there is a folder with the module name underneath `javadoc` that holds the `*.html` files for the classes and where the `doc-files` need to end up, too.

So I came to this:

```
javadoc {
  …
  doLast {
    var moduleName = Tools.obtainModuleName( project.sourceSets.main )
    var targetDir = moduleName.map( "/%s"::formatted ).orElse( "" )
    copy {
      from "$projectDir/src/main/java"
      into "$project.docsDir/javadoc$targetDir"
      include "**/doc-files/*"
    }
  }
}
```

`Tools.obtainModuleName()` is a function that gets the name of the Java module from the `module-info.java` file in the project:

```java
public static final Optional<String> obtainModuleName( final SourceSet sourceSet )
{
    Optional<String> retValue = Optional.empty();

    final var directorySet = sourceSet.getAllJava();
    final var moduleDefinitionFile = directorySet.getFiles()
        .stream()
        .filter( File::exists )
        .filter( File::isFile )
        .filter( f -> f.getName().equals( MODULE_DEFINITION ) )
        .findFirst()
        .map( File::toPath );
    if( moduleDefinitionFile.isPresent() )
    {
        try( final var lines = lines( moduleDefinitionFile.get() ) )
        {
            final var contents = lines.collect( joining() );
            final var pattern = compile( ".*module\\s+(\\S+)\\s*\\{.*" );
            final var matcher = pattern.matcher( contents );
            if( matcher.matches() )
            {
                retValue = Optional.ofNullable( matcher.group( 1 ) );
            }
        }
        catch( final IOException e )
        {
            throw new Error( e );
        }
    }

    //---* Done *----------------------------------------------------------
    return retValue;
}   //  obtainModuleName()
```

---

Unfortunately, this is still not the solution …

The underlying problem is that Gradle's JavaDoc task works on the *same* `SourceSet` as the Java compiler task – and the latter does not accept anything else than `*.java` files.

Just copying the `doc-files` folders from the source to the JavaDoc folder as the last action of the JavaDoc task does only seem to work properly, because the JavaDoc tool itself (that one from `$JDK_HOME/bin/javadoc`) also *processes* other files than just `*.java` – at least it does something with `*.html` files: you can use the usual JavaDoc tags, like `{@code …}` or `{@link …}` or even custom tags in there.

Just adding the `doc-files` folders and their contents to the `sourceSet` will not help, too. In my case, it results in an error message about an illegal package name for the files in the `doc-files` folder because there are hyphens somewhere in a folder name (same path works fine for the Java sources …).

I am currently working on a solution to convince Gradle's JavaDoc task to work on the files in `doc-files`, too. Stay tuned …